# Cannot read property 'google' of undefined when i use followup

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

When a user login i need to capture the actions_intent_SIGN_IN event and redirect it to the event that was triggered before login.

intent that captures actions_intent_SIGN_IN looks like this :

```
module.exports = function intentHandlesignin(agent) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
          let conv = agent.conv();
          console.debug('nextIntent : ', conv.data.nextIntent);
          console.debug('AccountNext: ', conv.data.account);
          conv.followup(conv.data.nextIntent,{
            account: conv.data.account,
          });
          agent.add(conv);
          resolve();
        });
      }
```

When this is triggered i get the following error message :

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'google' of undefined
at V2Agent.addActionsOnGoogle_ (/functions/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/v2-agent.js:342:24)
at WebhookClient.addResponse_ (/functions/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:279:19)
at WebhookClient.add (/functions/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:254:12)
at /functions/intent-handlesignin.js:24:15
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at intentHandlesignin (/functions/intent-handlesignin.js:16:12)
at /functions/index.js:124:52
at WebhookClient.handleRequest (/functions/node_modules/dialogflow-fulfillment/src/dialogflow-fulfillment.js:313:44)
at exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment.functions.https.onRequest (/functions/index.js:139:15)
at cloudFunction (/functions/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/providers/https.js:57:9)
```

From what i would tell this was a bug that was fixed in latest version of Dialogflow-fulfilment (0.6.1), but that doesn't solve the problem for me.

Any advice here? Am i using followup in the wrong way or is this a bug also?